# Ignoring x% of front part of each bin in scipy.stats.binned_statistic

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, statistics

The input data I have is basically a step and hold ramp function.

The output data spikes at the start each of these hold regions.

Here is the data in a figure, input in green, output in blue

[image]

I would like to take the average of the regions just after the spikes (Essentially the red regions in the plot)

It seems like the [binned_statistics](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binned_statistic.html) method in the scipy package would work great for this, but I don't see how I could remove the spikes from the averaging.

What I've got so far:

```
avg_in, avg_out = stats.binned_statistic(input, [input, output], 'mean', bins=12)[0]
```

Ideally I would ignore the first 10% of each bin or something.

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18OuaZ4Qls0DpCBwGwT2laxB4f9xEkY6Z/view?usp=sharing) is some sample data. Im using pandas to read it in.

Comment: How do you provide your data? I suggest adding a sample input.

Comment: Added link to some input/output data

Comment: This dataset is rather loosely connected to your description of the problem. Are you sure this is the right dataset?

Comment: Do you already have information on where the red regions are, i.e. the regions you want to take the mean of?

Comment: @Mr.T Oops sorry about that, I have a continuous ramp too, didnt mean to put that here. Fixed the link

Comment: @Graipher No the goal is to get the information from the red regions. I have something that loosely works, but was hoping there was something similar to this binned_statistics method that could help

Comment: @JoshWilkins I mean do you have (or can easily construct) a vector containing the indices of which values to keep (or not keep, either way)? In that case you could use masked arrays (in addition to some way to group them by step).

Comment: I am currently using pandas `groupby` and `cut` methods `groupby(pd.cut(input, np.arange(min(input), max(input), 1)['index'].apply(np.array).reset_index()` to get these regions but seems like overkill. Also, it would be awesome to reuse this binned statistics method since I also use it in my continuous ramp dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Binned_statistic](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binned_statistic.html) accepts an array of scalars instead of the bin number, therefore you can create bins of unequal size. So you could do this:

```
from scipy import stats
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", sep = ",")

#number of steps
n = 12
#percentage of the signal dismissed at the start of each step
p = 10
#length of the trace
points = df.Input.count()
#create bin_array of n steps, each step consisting of two steps with p% and 100-p%
bin_array = [0]
for i in range(n):
    bin_array.extend([int((i + float(p) / 100) * points) // n, ((i + 1) * points) // n])

#perform statistics on bins
avg_in, avg_out = stats.binned_statistic(df.index, [df.Input, df.Output], 'mean', bins = bin_array)[0]

#remove the values from the initial p% from each output list
avg_in = [item for i, item in enumerate(avg_in) if i % 2]
avg_out = [item for i, item in enumerate(avg_out) if i % 2]
print(avg_in)
print(avg_out)
#Sample output
#[64.73489552821727, 54.76841077703991, 44.807889084164074, 34.81446700507611, 24.850087873462492, 14.878445919562749, 4.894278461238032, -5.047188598203949, -15.02405780121078, -24.98881296368496, -35.01091583675023, -44.954373291681186]
#[6.313569615309482, 7.204238578680037, 7.448781487990606, 7.6773818820770625, 7.239388791251814, 7.5633404919951595, 7.317807068931801, 7.189217102694274, 6.9391818004296795, 6.780327996876248, 6.049744190587788, 5.693360015618928]
```

But Graipher's idea to work with masked panda arrays is great, you should go for it. I tag the question with `pandas` to attract the right people.

Comment: Took me a while to figure out what you just did, but I see it now. Would it make more sense to filter out the bin regions you don't want before taking the statistics on the bins?

Comment: On second thought, I'm not sure you could do this. It would try to create ranges where you didn't want them to be regardless

Comment: Imho this scipy function does not allow to perform the statistics on selected bins. If you hadn't said that you wanted to dismiss the initial 10% of each step, I would have discarded the first and last 10%, because in my measurements the last part is sometimes also not reliable. Basically just a slightly different bin array like [0.1, 0.8, 0.2, 0.8, ..., 0.8, 0.1].

Comment: I'll probably end up discarding the last 10% the data as well, but wasn't initially sure.